Why am I getting cocoapods installation error?
I am getting the following installation error for cocoapods:
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  A file_selector_macos
  A firebase_database
  A firebase_storage
  A sqflite
  R FirebaseFirestore
  - FlutterMacOS
  - audio_session
  - cloud_firestore
  - device_info_plus
  - firebase_auth
  - firebase_core
  - just_audio
  - package_info_plus
  - path_provider_foundation
  - screen_retriever
  - sentry_flutter
  - wakelock_macos
  - window_manager

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `FlutterMacOS` from `Flutter/ephemeral`
-> Fetching podspec for `audio_session` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/audio_session/macos`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/macos`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `device_info_plus` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/device_info_plus/macos`
-> Fetching podspec for `file_selector_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/file_selector_macos/macos`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/macos`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/macos`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_database` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/macos`
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/macos`
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '10.25.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `just_audio` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/just_audio/macos`
-> Fetching podspec for `package_info_plus` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/package_info_plus/macos`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`
-> Fetching podspec for `screen_retriever` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/screen_retriever/macos`
-> Fetching podspec for `sentry_flutter` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/sentry_flutter/macos`
-> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/darwin`
-> Fetching podspec for `wakelock_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/wakelock_macos/macos`
-> Fetching podspec for `window_manager` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/window_manager/macos`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Ignoring ffi-1.16.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.16.3
Ignoring debug-1.9.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine debug --version 1.9.1
Ignoring racc-1.7.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.7.3
Ignoring rbs-3.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine rbs --version 3.4.0
internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require': dlopen(/Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): Symbol not found: _rb_cFalseClass (LoadError) Referenced from: <78C1BA86-719D-3D76-A5C4-3E658376DF0D> /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle Expected in:     <52EB5BCC-A250-360A-9C20-4D54FC8ED9AF> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/bin/ruby - /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:5:in rescue in <top (required)>' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:2:in <top (required)>'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in <top (required)>' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in <top (required)>'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in download_typhoeus_impl_async' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in download_and_save_with_retries_async'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in download_file_async' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in download_file'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in refresh_metadata' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in initialize'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in initialize' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in new'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in block in source_from_path' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in source_from_path'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in block in aggregate_with_repos' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in map'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in aggregate_with_repos' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in aggregate'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in all' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in repo_information'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in stack' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in report'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in report_error' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in handle_exception'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in rescue in run' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in run'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in run' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in <top (required)>'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in load' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in '
internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require': cannot load such file -- 3.3/ffi_c (LoadError) from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:3:in <top (required)>' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in <top (required)>'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in <top (required)>' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in download_typhoeus_impl_async'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in download_and_save_with_retries_async' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in download_file_async'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in download_file' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in refresh_metadata'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in initialize' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in initialize'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in new' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in block in source_from_path'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in source_from_path' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in block in aggregate_with_repos'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in map' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in aggregate_with_repos'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in aggregate' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in all'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in repo_information' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in stack'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in report' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in report_error'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in handle_exception' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in rescue in run'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in run' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in run'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in <top (required)>' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in load'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in <main>' <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require': dlopen(/Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): Symbol not found: _rb_cFalseClass (LoadError)
Referenced from: <78C1BA86-719D-3D76-A5C4-3E658376DF0D> /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle
Expected in:     <52EB5BCC-A250-360A-9C20-4D54FC8ED9AF> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/bin/ruby - /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi_c.bundle
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:5:in rescue in <top (required)>'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:2:in <top (required)>' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in <top (required)>'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in <top (required)>' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in download_typhoeus_impl_async'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in download_and_save_with_retries_async' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in download_file_async'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in download_file' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in refresh_metadata'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in initialize' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in initialize'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in new' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in block in source_from_path'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in source_from_path' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:53:in block in sources'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:53:in map' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:53:in sources'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add_cdn.rb:38:in block in run' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add_cdn.rb:36:in run' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:45:in create_source_with_url'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in find_or_create_source_with_url' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:179:in block in sources'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in map' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in sources'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1081:in block in resolve_dependencies' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in resolve_dependencies' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in analyze'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in analyze' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in block in resolve_dependencies'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in resolve_dependencies'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in install!' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in run'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in run' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in run'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in <top (required)>' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in load'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in <main>' <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require': cannot load such file -- 3.3/ffi_c (LoadError)
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/lib/ffi.rb:3:in <top (required)>'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in <top (required)>' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in <top (required)>'
from internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:136:in require' from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.1/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in require'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in download_typhoeus_impl_async' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in download_and_save_with_retries_async'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in download_file_async' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in download_file'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in refresh_metadata' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in initialize'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in initialize' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in new'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in block in source_from_path' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in source_from_path'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:53:in block in sources' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:53:in map'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:53:in sources' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add_cdn.rb:38:in block in run'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add_cdn.rb:36:in run'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:45:in create_source_with_url' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in find_or_create_source_with_url'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:179:in block in sources' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in map'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in sources' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1081:in block in resolve_dependencies'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in resolve_dependencies'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in analyze' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in analyze'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in block in resolve_dependencies' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in resolve_dependencies' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in install!'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in run' from /Users/mathewprasanth/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in run'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in run' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in <top (required)>'
from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in load' from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in '
Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run:
sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
Error: Error running pod install
Exited (1).
I tried the above command and still getting the same error.
